# Prediction interval using predict and NeweyWest in R

Tags: r, regression, prediction-interval, robust-standard-error, neweywest

I have a basic linear regression model I fitted to a time series. Unfortunately I have to account for autocorrelation and heteroskedasicity in the model and I have done so with the NeweyWest function from the sandwich package in R while analyzing the coefficients.

Now I would like to create prediction intervals using the predict() function (or any other function) while utilizing the NeweyWest matrix/SEs.

As this is the first quesiton I post on here and my experinece in R is very limited here is some information:

```
LMModel = lm(Return~Sentiment, data=Time Series)
```

**This is the function I used for my coefficient testing:**

```
coeftest(LMModel , vcov=NeweyWest(LMModel , lag=27, ar.method="ols"))
```

**I would like thsi function to use NeweyWest in some way:**

```
predict(LMModel, newdata, interval = "prediction", level = 0.95)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I recognize that you want to account for the autocorrelation in the data, but why are you using standard linear regression for a time series? Why not use actual time-series (ie Box-Jenkins) methods? Also, what do you mean by wanting to "predict"? Do you want to *forecast* future values? While this is posed as an R coding question, I wonder if this is a conceptual issue masked by a coding question.

Comment: Actually autorcorrelation and heteroskedasicity. I use the simple linear regression because similar work done in my field doesn't really use any other models for some reason. My next step would be to look at some ARMA models if that is what you are refering to by Box-Jenkins. I might have misspoke regarding pure time series the independent variable is a behavorial indicator between 1 and -1 of a weekly survey and it is autocorrelated. 

I want to calculate prediction intervals with the predict function in R. So the question I want to answer is how do my returns react (in intervals) with X sent

Comment: Hi @BernieB, did you ever find out a way to do this in the end? thx